# Why ExecJS constantly uses 100% CPU?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, cpu-usage, execjs

I'm using Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 4.2.5 and Capistrano to deploy, but after my latest commit suddenly server always uses 100% CPU. I used htop and saw command `nodejs tmp/execjs` use all the CPU.

[CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KzOT.png)

Can anyone explain this and tell me a solution for this problem, please?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

This often takes 3-4 hours, and this problem is appear when I add gem 'local_time'

This is my bundle list

`* CFPropertyList (2.3.2)
  * actionmailer (4.2.5)
  * actionpack (4.2.5)
  * actionview (4.2.5)
  * activejob (4.2.5)
  * activemodel (4.2.5)
  * activerecord (4.2.5)
  * activesupport (4.2.5)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (3.5.0)
  * addressable (2.4.0)
  * arel (6.0.3)
  * autoprefixer-rails (6.3.6.1)
  * awesome_print (1.6.1)
  * axiom-types (0.1.1)
  * bcrypt (3.1.10)
  * best_in_place (3.0.3)
  * bootstrap (4.0.0.alpha3 f6a7b7b)
  * bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.6.1.1)
  * builder (3.2.2)
  * bundler (1.11.2)
  * carrierwave (0.10.0)
  * carrierwave_backgrounder (0.4.2)
  * certified (1.0.0)
  * chartkick (2.0.0)
  * chronic (0.10.2)
  * chunky_png (1.3.5)
  * ckeditor (4.1.6 93c1b19)
  * climate_control (0.0.3)
  * cocaine (0.5.8)
  * coercible (1.0.0)
  * coffee-rails (4.1.0)
  * coffee-script (2.4.1)
  * coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
  * compass (1.0.3)
  * compass-core (1.0.3)
  * compass-import-once (1.0.5)
  * compass-rails (3.0.2)
  * composite_primary_keys (8.1.2)
  * concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
  * connection_pool (2.2.0)
  * cookiejar (0.3.0)
  * curb (0.8.8)
  * datetimepicker-rails (4.7.16 36d21ce)
  * dentaku (2.0.7)
  * descendants_tracker (0.0.4)
  * devise (3.5.2)
  * doorkeeper (3.1.0)
  * dotenv (2.1.0)
  * dotenv-rails (2.1.0)
  * dropzonejs-rails (0.7.2)
  * em-http-request (1.1.3)
  * em-socksify (0.3.1)
  * enum_accessor (2.3.0)
  * enum_help (0.0.14)
  * equalizer (0.0.11)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * eventmachine (1.2.0.1)
  * excon (0.45.4)
  * execjs (2.6.0)
  * faraday (0.9.2)
  * faraday_middleware (0.10.0)
  * faye (1.1.2)
  * faye-websocket (0.10.4)
  * ffi (1.9.10)
  * filterrific (2.0.5)
  * fission (0.5.0)
  * fog (1.36.0)
  * fog-aliyun (0.1.0)
  * fog-atmos (0.1.0)
  * fog-aws (0.7.6)
  * fog-brightbox (0.10.1)
  * fog-core (1.35.0)
  * fog-dynect (0.0.2)
  * fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
  * fog-google (0.1.0)
  * fog-json (1.0.2)
  * fog-local (0.2.1)
  * fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
  * fog-profitbricks (0.0.5)
  * fog-radosgw (0.0.4)
  * fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
  * fog-sakuracloud (1.4.0)
  * fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
  * fog-softlayer (1.0.2)
  * fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
  * fog-terremark (0.1.0)
  * fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
  * fog-voxel (0.1.0)
  * fog-xenserver (0.2.2)
  * fog-xml (0.1.2)
  * font-awesome-sass (4.4.0)
  * formatador (0.2.5)
  * foursquare2 (2.0.2)
  * friendly_id (5.1.0)
  * geocoder (1.3.4)
  * globalid (0.3.6)
  * grape (0.13.0)
  * grape-entity (0.5.1)
  * grape-kaminari (0.1.8)
  * grape-swagger (0.20.3)
  * grape-swagger-rails (0.2.1)
  * groupdate (3.0.1)
  * hashie (3.4.3)
  * high_voltage (2.4.0)
  * http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
  * i18n (0.7.0)
  * ice_nine (0.11.1)
  * inflecto (0.0.2)
  * ipaddress (0.8.0)
  * jbuilder (2.3.2)
  * jquery-rails (4.0.5)
  * jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
  * json (1.8.3)
  * jwt (1.5.2)
  * kaminari (0.16.3)
  * local_time (1.0.3)
  * loofah (2.0.3)
  * mail (2.6.4)
  * mime-types (3.1)
  * mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
  * mini_magick (4.3.6)
  * mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
  * minitest (5.9.0)
  * momentjs-rails (2.10.6 3d35d16)
  * money (6.7.0)
  * multi_json (1.11.2)
  * multi_xml (0.5.5)
  * multipart-post (2.0.0)
  * nilify_blanks (1.2.1)
  * nokogiri (1.6.8)
  * obfuscate_id (0.2.0)
  * orm_adapter (0.5.0)
  * paper_trail (4.0.0)
  * pg (0.18.3)
  * pg_search (1.0.6)
  * phonelib (0.5.4)
  * pkg-config (1.1.7)
  * polyamorous (1.1.0)
  * programr (0.0.1 af04cc1)
  * puma (3.1.0)
  * pundit (1.0.1)
  * rack (1.6.4)
  * rack-accept (0.4.5)
  * rack-cors (0.4.0)
  * rack-mount (0.8.3)
  * rack-protection (1.5.3)
  * rack-test (0.6.3)
  * rails (4.2.5)
  * rails-assets-tether (1.1.1)
  * rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
  * rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
  * railties (4.2.5)
  * rake (11.2.2)
  * rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
  * rb-inotify (0.9.7)
  * redis (3.2.2)
  * request_store (1.2.0)
  * responders (2.1.0)
  * rubyzip (1.2.0)
  * sass (3.4.19)
  * sass-rails (5.0.4)
  * scatter_swap (0.0.3)
  * sendgrid (1.2.0)
  * sidekiq (4.0.1)
  * simple_form (3.2.0)
  * sinatra (1.4.6)
  * sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.1.1)
  * sprockets (3.6.3)
  * sprockets-rails (3.1.1)
  * squeel (1.2.3 5542266)
  * thor (0.19.1)
  * thread_safe (0.3.5)
  * tilt (2.0.1)
  * turbolinks (2.5.3)
  * twilio-ruby (4.2.1)
  * tzinfo (1.2.2)
  * uglifier (2.7.2)
  * unicode (0.4.4.2)
  * virtus (1.0.5)
  * warden (1.2.3)
  * websocket-driver (0.6.4)
  * websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
  * whenever (0.9.4)
  * xml-simple (1.1.5)`

Thank you so much for your helps

Comment: how long does it stay that way?

Comment: Could you run `bundle list` in your project directory and provide the output?

Comment: It's probably busy compiling all those assets as fast as it can :)

Comment: Hi, guys, I updated bundle list above, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in this week, and in my case I mistakenly removed the tmp/cache in the beanstalk postdeploy step. That's why the servers have to
compile again and consume 100% CPU